# Kafka popular hashtags counting

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka and Spark to count the most popular hashtags on twitter. So, this is the scala object I want to run:

```
package spark.example

import java.util.HashMap

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{ KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord }
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

/**
  * A Spark Streaming - Kafka integration to receive twitter
  * data from kafka topic and find the popular hashtags
  *
  * Arguments: <zkQuorum> <consumer-group> <topics> <numThreads>
  * <zkQuorum>       - The zookeeper hostname
  * <consumer-group> - The Kafka consumer group
  * <topics>         - The kafka topic to subscribe to
  * <numThreads>     - Number of kafka receivers to run in parallel
  *
  * More discussion at stdatalabs.blogspot.com
  *
  * @author Sachin Thirumala
  */

object KafkaSparkPopularHashTags {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[6]").setAppName("Spark Streaming - Kafka Producer - PopularHashTags").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

  conf.set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

//sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

// Create an array of arguments: zookeeper hostname/ip,consumer group, topicname, num of threads
val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args

// Set the Spark StreamingContext to create a DStream for every 2 seconds
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

// Map each topic to a thread
val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
// Map value from the kafka message (k, v) pair
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
// Filter hashtags
val hashTags = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).filter(_.startsWith("#"))

// Get the top hashtags over the previous 60/10 sec window
val topCounts60 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60))
  .map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }


val topCounts10 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(10))
  .map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }


lines.print()

// Print popular hashtags
topCounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val topList = rdd.take(10)
  println("\nPopular topics in last 60 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
  topList.foreach { case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }
})

topCounts10.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val topList = rdd.take(10)
  println("\nPopular topics in last 10 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
  topList.foreach { case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }
})

lines.count().map(cnt => "Received " + cnt + " kafka messages.").print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

But everytime I tried to run the code with the following parameters:
localhost:2181 spark-streaming-consumer-group tweets 2
(where topic 'tweets' has already been created and TwitterProducer is running) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.spark.util.SystemClock
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.liftedTree1$1(JobGenerator.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.<init>(JobGenerator.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.<init>(JobScheduler.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:75)
at spark.example.KafkaSparkPopularHashTags$.main(KafkaSparkPopularHashTags.scala:48)
at spark.example.KafkaSparkPopularHashTags.main(KafkaSparkPopularHashTags.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.util.SystemClock.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
```

As the error suggest there is something wrong on line 48, which is:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
```

It seems like the system is not able to instantiate the object.
Any suggestion to solve this problem?
Other info: I am using Scala 2.12 and I have already tried to downgrade to Scala 2.11 and even 2.10.
I am trying to reproduce this experiment: http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2016/09/spark-streaming-part-3-real-time.html

Comment: would suggest to check version of dependencies.

Comment: Agree this is a dependency problem, not a problem in the code you've shown us. A particular version of Spark expects a particular major version of Scala (2.10, 2.11, or (in some version of Spark that isn't officially released yet) 2.12). Libraries built for different Scala major versions cannot be mixed. The current stable version of Spark uses Scala 2.11, so you probably want to stick with 2.11 and make sure you are only using 2.11 libraries.

Comment: After a lot of attemps I found out that I had to use Scala version 2.11.1
Thank you for your precious help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE] After a lot of attemps I found out that I had to use Scala version 2.11.1 Thank you for your precious help